# why samba share files are not able to access by some user for some time?

Tags: server, networking, security, samba, file-sharing

I'm running samba on Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS, I've some folders on samba share and created some user to access it, but suddenly some of the user are not able to access it for a certain time only.

For i.e:

There are 5 users as A,B,C,D,E and there are two folders in samba share name as "test" and "develop"

"test" doesn't have any user access password but "develop" has user access with password.

Now A,C,E are able to access folder "develop" with their samba password but B,D are not able to access with their samba password for some time only or if I use B-username & password in A or C laptop its working fine at that time.

While connecting to samba share, below error message appears:

```
An error has occurred while connecting [drive letter]: to [share name] Microsoft Windows Network: the local device name is already in use. 
This connection has not been restored.
```

This happens randomly with the username & laptops.

I restarted entire network & server & laptop but still doesn't work.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows issue, not Linux/Samba. It means that there is already a drive mapped to that drive letter. I have seen it happen that even after disconnecting a drive mapping in Windows that it still seems to "hold on" to that drive letter. Running this from the Windows client should free it up:

```
net use * /del /yes
net use /persistent:no
```

Also, with Windows, you cannot map two drives to the same server with different credentials. If you use a username/password with develop, then you must use that same username/password with test.

Comment: you mean that user mapped to the drive letter should be different for all the user.

Comment: I just mean that say you are trying to map "test" to drive letter t:. The error will pop up when drive letter t: is already in use, either from a flash drive, etc. or a previous mapped network drive. The drive letter does not have to be different for every Windows client, and I would suggest against that, as, in my experience, most users will refer to the drive letters by letter. i.e. "Hey, I threw that on the T drive".

Comment: thanks 4 ur response, windows client:Lets say i've mapped my "test" folder to drive letter T: & "develop" folder as X:.I'm able access T drive because there is no username & password restriction for it.But when  i try to access "X" it ask username&password i enter the username&pass correctly and hit enter, it shows that error which i mention above:. Now what i do is go to another windows client & hit the same username & password for the "develop" folder it logs in without any probe!!

Comment: Are you connecting to the same file server for both the test and develop shares? In Windows, you cannot connect to the same server twice with different credentials. So, even though test doesn't require a username/password, you would have to give it one, if you are using a username/password for develop.

Comment: yes, I've two folders in same file server. But when i or other user connect to the folder "test" it doesn't ask any username&password, when i'm accessing the folder "develop" it prompt to enter username & password!! It also able to access but sometime it gives that error!!

Comment: When you map the drive you need to select "Use other credentials", or something like that and give it the same username/password.